# Json serialization issues

Tags: python, json, serialization

Probably a very basic question but I couldn't find an answer as either this requires knowledge that I don't have or not applicable to my case.

I'm running a simple python script to get some json responses. Basically I have a firewall and I need to 'read' some information from the configuration file.

Here is the interesting parts of my python script:

```
client = requests.session() 

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()

api_cmdb = 'api/v2/cmdb/'
api_monitor = 'api/v2/monitor/'



try:
    login = client.post(url + '/logincheck', data="username=" + name + "&secretkey=" + password, verify = False)
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
    requests.status_code = "Connection refused"

ini = client.cookies['ccsrftoken']
csrftoken = ini[1:-1]
client.headers.update({"X-CSRFTOKEN": csrftoken})


ae = client.get(url + api_cmdb + 'router/static', verify = False, params = {'vdom': 'root'})

#print json.dumps(vars(ae))

resp = ae.json()
pprint(resp)
client_logout = client.post(url + '/logout', verify = False)
client.close()
```

We get this result when using ae.json():

```
{u'build': 1547,
 u'http_method': u'GET',
 u'http_status': 200,
 u'name': u'static',
 u'path': u'router',
 u'results': [{u'blackhole': u'disable',
               u'comment': u'',
               u'device': u'port1',
               u'distance': 10,
               u'dst': u'0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0',
               u'dstaddr': u'',
               u'dynamic-gateway': u'disable',
               u'gateway': u'192.168.1.99',
               u'internet-service': 0,
               u'internet-service-custom': u'',
               u'link-monitor-exempt': u'disable',
               u'priority': 0,
etc.
```

What I don't understand is why when I issue print json.dumps(vars(ae)) or print json.dumps(ae) I get a:

```
raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <Response [200]> is not JSON serializable
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `ae` is a `Response` object. When you call `ae.json()` it returns a JSON representation of that response object, but trying to serialize it manually will throw an error because the `json` module has no idea how to turn a `Response` object into valid JSON. You should be calling something like

```
print json.dumps(ae.json())
```

which will get the JSON representation of the `Response` object using its own internal logic (the `.json()` method), and then print the string version of it.

Answer (score 1):

`vars(ae)` or `ae.__dict__` returns a dictionary of object attributes and values. If you examine it, you will see it doesn't only contain the body of the response (which is converted to json by calling `ae.json()`), but also many other attributes. In general some of them may be objects (in your case a `Response` object from `requests`) and not only simple types like strings, lists etc.

If you want to proceed further (if it makes any sense for you), you will need to proceed with your own `json.JSONEncoder` and `json.JSONDecoder` implementations.